# Formatting text using Apache POI 3.8 (HWPF)

Tags: apache-poi, hwpf

I am trying to insert the following text in the document using Apache POI 3.8:

> **[Bold]**[Normal],

but the output document has this:

> [Bold][Normal]

The code:

```java
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("empty.dot"));

        final Range range = doc.getRange();
        final CharacterRun cr1 = range.insertAfter("[Bold]");
        cr1.setBold(true);

        final CharacterRun cr2 = cr1.insertAfter("[Normal]");
        cr2.setBold(false);

        doc.write(new FileOutputStream("output.doc"));
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I think you might have issues trying it on the overall range. Can you try getting just one paragraph, and appending the runs to that, and see if that behaves better?

Comment: `final Range range = doc.getRange().getParagraph(0);` - doesn't help, the text is still [Bold][Normal]. I've tried the similar approach with XWPF and it works as intended, but I still need HWPF.

Answer (score -3):

I do it like this. Using POI 3.11

```
paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
paragraph.setStyle(DOG_HEAD_STYLE);
XWPFRun tmpRun = paragraph.createRun();
tmpRun.setText("non bold text ");

tmpRun = paragraph.createRun();
tmpRun.setBold(true);
tmpRun.setText("bold text");
tmpRun = paragraph.createRun();
tmpRun.setBold(false);
tmpRun.setText(" non bold text again");
```

Comment: The OP explicitly says they want to use HWPF, so how does this XWPF code help them?